# Set style to class names that have a random number

Tags: css, class, random, styles

If I have a class like

`.pin_12345_btn_select`

Where the 12345 is a random number (which can be 5 to 12 characters long)

Is there a way I can set a single class style to all of these that are present in the site using a random number as above.

For example;

`.pin_#####_btn_select {
  Z-index:99;
  width:220px;
}`

Thanks

Greg

Comment: You can use `[class^="pin_"]` to target classes that start with "pin_"

Comment: Excellent thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors **providing** the start and end text is always the same and only the random number changes.

```
  [class^="pin_"][class$="_btn_select"]
```

The first selector choses any class that **starts** with the required text where the second selects classes that **end** with the chosen text. If we make them a single selector then.....

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

[class^="pin_"][class$="_btn_select"] {
  background: green;
}

[class$="_btn_select"] {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin_12345_btn_select">Should work</div>
<div class="12345_btn_select">Wont Work Fully</div>
<div class="pin_12345">Definitely won't work</div>
<div class="pin_random_btn_select">Should work</div>
```